# Max size of a form, enable Maximize Windows form state C#

Tags: c#, forms, resize

Currently I am creating a form where the user should not be allowed to change the width or height of the Form, but they should be able to maximize the form when they want to.
I've tried the following:

```
Form myForm = new Form() {
    MaximumSize = new Size(500, 500),
    MinimumSize = new Size(500, 500),
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
};
```

The problem is that when the form displays it's size is `width=500` and `height=500`, but I would like it to be maximized.

Is there another way to stop the user of adjusting the height and width?

Comment: Do you want the form maximized, or do you want it 500x500 pixels?  You can't have both.  As for preventing them changing the form size, you can set the FormBorderStyle to one of the fixed options.  This will prevent them resizing it.

Comment: It's basically preventing them from changing the size

Comment: @BobG If you would write your comment into an answer I will be able to give you the Green Tick. It answered my question. Thanks man

Comment: Done.  Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want the form maximized, or do you want it 500x500 pixels? You can't have both at the same time.

As for preventing them changing the form size, you can set the **FormBorderStyle** to one of the fixed options. This will prevent them resizing it.

**From MSDN**: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle(v=vs.110).aspx][1]

The border style of the form determines how the outer edge of the form appears. In addition to changing the border display for a form, certain border styles prevent the form from being sized. For example, the FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog border style changes the border of the form to that of a dialog box and prevents the form from being resized. The border style can also affect the size or availability of the caption bar section of a form.

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to solve. A form has a function called SizeChanged. If you press the maximize button it won't trigger so this function can be used so solve the problem. You just set the window size in SizeChanged to 500, 500 and your problem will be solved. There may be fancier ways to solve it but this option is to my opinion the easiest.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Size = new Size(500, 500);
}

private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Size = new Size(500, 500);
}
```

This should do the job :) Success!